# How much should a wallet friendly entry level road bike weigh?

Tags: road-bike

Just bought the Merida Scultura 100 and it weighs 8.5 kgs. Am slowly beginning to realize the importance of bike weight when it comes to average speed.

Comment: It should weight more than the wallet.  (And the importance of bike weight vs average speed is "virtually none", at least on the flat.)

Comment: That's quite light, not superlight but stuff that's lighter will cost exorbitantly more.   In 10-20 years,  when you've worn out this bike, then see what you can afford.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Nikhil. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're asking [ask] is useful also. There are three opinion based aspects to this question: what does wallet friendly mean, what is an entry level road bike, and what should it weigh? In the end, the most important things are does it fit you, and are the gears what you need? Weight, within reason (ie < 10 kg), is not that important.

Answer (score 2):

A "wallet friendly" entry level bike should weigh as little or as much as your wallet allows.

The key here is **entry level**. For the vast majority of people in the market for a entry level bike (and most racing cyclists), the weight of the bike is not the limiting factor. All things considered, 8.5kg is not absurdly heavy for a bike, it's actually a shade lighter than my current racing bike, which is more than capable on hilly and flat races.

Bottom line, lightweight and wallet-friendly are usually mutually exclusive when it comes to bikes. Don't worry about the weight, and enjoy the ride.

Comment: Whenever I am tempted to think of a lighter bike, I ask myself, "would it be easier to lose weight from the bike, or from my body?"  So far, the answer has been "from my body", so I put the wallet away and jump on the bike instead.

Comment: @rclocher3 - Of course, when you then ask "OK, how much weight have I lost from my body?" the answer is usually disappointing.

Comment: Speak for yourself, @DanielRHicks!  Ha ha